# Is it safe to buy a dedicated linux server?

Tags: linux, security

I'm planning to buy a dedicated linux server.

I'll receive the root password and I'll change it .And also I'll have ssh access.
It is safe for me too keep personal data on this server ?

I mean , If i change the root password is any way somebody from the datacenter where the server is located ,to access the server files while this is running , if I change the root password?

I know the root password can be reset if they restart server and boot with a install cd or flash .

But if they do not reset my root pass , can they access my files using a usb cable or some physical port so I do not know?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there is no security solution that can deal with physical access in a hostile environment.

They could pull anything they want off there. If you disable all remote access, they can simply pull the physical disks and read them.

If you encrypt it, then there are a variety of attacks (such as man in the middle, since they control the network) that could expose the key with relatively little effort.

The *only* realistic way to prevent access is to encrypt your files on your end and never ever ever send either the raw files or the key. However, this only applies if all you want the server to do is store files.

If you wanted to, for example, host a website with database on this machine, there are no practical security techniques at this time to prevent them from just reading the decryption keys and data from memory or disk.

However, this is not to say that putting a bit of effort into security/encryption would be bad. Using an encrypted partition or file container would likely be effective at slowing down a rogue actor (ie one without the support of the company) sufficiently that unless they targeted you specifically, they'd likely move on to an easier target.

To close: most major corporate hosts are relatively safe. There are precautions on their end to prevent staff from pulling files and data from customer machines. It can still happen, but is very unlikely.